# Error trying to execute method after error catch

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this jsf code

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{agreement.serviceId}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Enter" action="#{agreement.build}" />
    <h:form rendered="#{!agreement.valid}">
      <h:outputText value="Service id not valid. Please try again"/>
    </h:form>   
<h:form>
```

This is the scoped bean's build method.

```
public String build(){
  try{
     ...//lots of backend logic
     valid = true;
     return "/agreementDetail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
  }catch(Exception e){
     valid = false;
     return null;
  }
}
```

Basically, here's the behavior I need:

The user inputs a serviceId. If this service id is valid, it redirects the user to the agreementDetail.xhtml page. If false, the user remains in the main.xhtml page and the "Service id not valid..." message is rendered.

This is what's happening:

If the user inputs a correct service id, everything works fine. If the user returns to main.xhtml and inputs an incorrect service id, the error is displayed correctly. But now, if the user inputs a correct service id, the build() method **is not executed.** (I've confirmed this with logging).

Basically, once the user inputs a wrong value, the build() method won't be executed ever again unless the user signs off and signs in again. Clearly, something's going on when the build() finds an error and catches the exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: The code posted so far does not seem to match the problem description. The action method is declared `private`. This should never have been executed and instead have thrown an EL exception on first invocation. By the way, why are you not just using faces messages with `<h:messages>`? That nested form is an ugly approach and results only in [syntactically invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. The method is public, I just wrote it down incorrectly. I'll make an edit to set it public. Also, I know <h:messages> is better, I just found this behavior interesting and I'm trying to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting forms in your code. That is not allowed in JSF/HTML. You should replace the inner form with a `<h:panelGroup>` and everything should be fine.

Comment: He is not submitting from inside the nested form, so that's unlikely the cause. See also my comment on the question.